# Protocols and inheritance - access child protocol properties in a parent class?

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols

I am building a framework where I would like to have new class instances inherit from a base class `Vehicle` while also conforming to a protocol `VehicleProtocol`. `Vehicle` is intended to be used for inheritance only and should not be used/instantiated directly (i.e. should never conform to `VehicleProtocol`).

The desired outcomes are:

- New vehicle classes must have access to shared base methods (i.e. inherit from `Vehicle`)
- New vehicle classes must require a vehicle name string (i.e. conform to `VehicleProtocol`)
- New vehicle classes, upon initialization, automatically call a base class method without having to override the method in the child class, or manually call it every time

Given this example code:

```
protocol VehicleProtocol: Vehicle {
    var vehicleName: String { get }
}

class Vehicle: NSObject {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.startEngine()
    }

    func someSharedMethod() {}
    
    private func startEngine() {
        // how to access `vehicleName`?
        print("Starting engine for \(vehicleName)...")
    }
}

class Truck: Vehicle, VehicleProtocol {

    var vehicleName: String = "My Truck"

    func someUniqueMethod() {}
}
```

How can I make it so that, when I initialize a new instance of `Truck`, the base class method `startEngine()` is called and its output is "Starting engine for My Truck"? Such as:

```
let vehicle = Truck()
// prints "Starting engine for My Truck..."
```

EDIT
Adding more context, the below code gets me 99% of the way there:

```
class Vehicle: NSObject {
    
    var vehicleName: String {
        return ""
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        startEngine()
    }

    func startEngine() {
        guard !vehicleName.isEmpty else {
            // handle error
            return
        }
        print("Starting engine for \(vehicleName)...")
    }
}

class Truck: Vehicle {

    override var vehicleName: String {
        return "My Truck"
    }
}
```

However, the key thing I'm hoping to achieve is to make assigning the `vehicleName` property *absolutely required when creating a new vehicle class,* which protocols do well in my limited understanding. But perhaps there's a better way?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding a protocol extension with your default implementation of `startEngine()`, as described by CloudBalancing, you should have your base `Vehicle` Class conform to the `VehicleProtocol`:

```
protocol VehicleProtocol: Vehicle {
    var vehicleName: String { get }

    func startEngine()
} 

class Vehicle: VehicleProtocol {

    var vehicleName: String
    //The rest of your Vehicle stuff goes here.
}
```

The fact that your protocol includes a `vehicleName` property means that any object that conforms to that protocol must also have a vehicle name property. It doesn’t get added automatically.

You could have your `Vehicle` base class include a `vehicleName` property and a `startEngine()` method without needing protocols. Any class that inherits from your Vehicle class will also have a `vehicleName` property and a `startEngine()` method.

Comment: I want `vehicleName` to be a required variable when creating a new vehicle class (i.e. I want the dev to be prompted - more automatic than just having to remember to set it), so that's why I went with a protocol. Is there a better way? Also, by defining `startEngine()` in the protocol, won't every class conforming to `VehicleProtocol` have to define a `startEngine` method? Sure, it could just call `super.startEngine()` but I would like to avoid having to re-define that method if possible. There are about 150 classes that will inherit from `Vehicle` and `VehicleProtocol`

Comment: Also, I'm looking for children of `Vehicle` to conform to `VehicleProtocol` - this would not be possible if `Vehicle` itself conforms due to redundancy

Comment: Children will inherit their conformance from the base class automatically. You would not be able to create children that don’t conform. If you give the base class a vehicleName property, children will inherit that property.